# Parking options for Toronto Pearson Airport (YYZ)

Tags: airport-transfer, safety, automobiles, security, yyz

I am planning a short, five-day trip out of the country in mid-June, in which I will be departing and returning to Pearson. Since I will be returning late at night, I'll need to park at or near the airport instead of being picked up.

After a bit of research, it seems like parking right at the airport is the most reliable option, but also the most expensive at $20 per day. The alternative parking places look much cheaper but reviews for places like Park 'n Fly are mixed or negative, with many complains about having to pay too much or unfriendly attendants/shuttle drivers.

I am wondering if parking at the airport is worth the extra money, as far as paying and security go. Alternatively, if it makes more sense to park somewhere else nearby, how secure are those lots, especially later at night? Should I be worried about walking in the parking lot or the security of my vehicle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use Park N Fly Valet at YYZ. I used economy once. It wasn't scary or dangerous, but it added a fairly significant amount of time on both ends of the trip waiting for a bus, as well as walking through the lot. With valet, my only issue is that sometimes I have to wait 5 or 10 minutes for my car to appear. (Every few years it's more than that and I become a VERY unhappy customer at them.) Usually, my car is there, waiting for me (and the engine running in the winter so the car is warm) when I get off the bus. I have never had an unfriendly driver, though I have no need for them to be friendly; I just need them to make the bus go where I need to be. Park N Fly coupons and coupon codes are easy to obtain; I get one on my web-checkin boarding pass whenever I fly Air Canada. On a recent trip for a week (Sun-Sat) it was going to be $136 and the coupon took $55 off that.

With the advent of the UP, you could construct a public transit solution where your car is at a GO station, where parking is free. You could also book a room at an airport hotel the day you leave, typically for a little over $100, that includes two weeks of free parking and use the hotel shuttle. But for a 5 day trip, I'd say go Park N Fly and find a coupon code.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed suggestions. How available is parking at GO stations? Might I get to one and not find a spot, considering I'll be flying out on a Saturday evening?

Comment: A Saturday evening won't be a problem. A weekday at 8am sure will be.